Finding all real values of $k$ so that the eqn. $(x^2-x+1)^2- 2kx (x^2+x+1) + (x^2+x+1)^2=0...$
Finding all real values of $k$ so that  $$f(x)=(x^2-x+1)^2-2kx(x^2+x+1)+(x^2+x+1)^2=0$$ has two or four real roots.
We can re-write this equation as
$g(y)=y^2+ky+1-k=0$, where $y=\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$. Next one can check that $1/3\le y\le 3, \forall x\in R.$
Case 1: $f(x)=0$ will have  two real roots if $g(y)=0$ has exactly one real root in $(1/3,3)$. This requires
$g(1/3)g(3)<0$ and we get $$k<-5~ \text{or}~ k>5/3.~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Case 2: $f(x)=0$ will have four real roots if $g(y)=0$ has both roots real in $(1/3,3)$. This requires $$ (i): B^2\ge 4AC\implies k \le -2\sqrt{2}-2 ~\text{or}~ k\ge 2\sqrt{2}-2 ~~\&$$
$$(ii): 1/3 <y_0=-k/2 < 3 \implies -6 < k<-2/3~~\&$$
$$(iii): g(1/3) >0 \implies 10/9-2k/3 >0~~\&$$
$$(iv): g(3) >0 \implies 10+2k>0.$$
The overlap of these intervals gives
$$ -5 < k < -2\sqrt{2}-2.~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
What could be other method/way of solving this problem?

You have to give a condition for $y$ because if not, for each value of $k$ you do have a curve of two variables, $y$ and $x$. Also you have to edit the title in which $y$ does not appear.

@Anne Bauval .- I think so, I agree with you.

I am extremely sorry as $y$ was wrongly printed in $f(x)$, I have removed it now.

I would like to multiply $f$ by $(x-1)$ and have cube identities.

For $k=-5$ you do have the two real roots $x=-\dfrac12(3\pm\sqrt5)$

@Piquito for $k=-5$ you have three real roots: yours, and $-1$.

A pretty generalizable approach is to use the discriminant or resultant. Here
$$
R := \operatorname{Res}(f, f') = -128(k^2 + 4k - 4)^2 (3k - 5)(k + 5).
$$
Now we know that $f$ has a double root if and only if $R = 0$. But moreover, the transition between having no real roots and having real roots is going to happen when $R = 0$. So we can solve $R = 0$ (which gives $\pm 2\sqrt2 - 2, 5/3, -5$) and check what happens in each interval. And this just requires picking a single point in the interval to check the behaviour. And we find exactly the intervals that you've stated.

Please give the Ref. for $Res( f,f')$.

@ZAhmed you can use any computer algebra system. I used Sage but you can also use Mathematica, Singular, Maple, ...

A number $x$ is a root iff $x\ne0$ and
$k=f(x)$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{(x^2-x+1)^2+(x^2+x+1)^2}{2x(x^2+x+1)}.$$
Let $$t:=x+\frac1x.$$ Then, $|t|\ge2$, and each $t$ corresponds to two distinct values of $x$, except $t=2$ or $-2$ (corresponding respectively to $x=1$ or $-1$), and
$$f(x)=g(t):=\frac{t^2+1}{t+1}.$$
This function $g$ has local extrema at $-1\pm\sqrt2$, and an elementary study of its graph proves that there are:

one solution $t>2$ (hence two solutions $x>0$) iff $k>g(2)=\frac53$,
one solution $t<-2$  (hence two solutions $x<0$) iff $k<g(-2)=-5$, or $k=g(-1-\sqrt2)=-2-2\sqrt2$ (a value you forgot),
two solutions $t<-2$ (hence four solutions $x<0$) iff $-5<k<-2-2\sqrt2$.


Another way: Check that $f(x)=0$ can be simplified to
$$x^4-kx^3+(3-k)x^2-kx+1=0 \implies (x^2+1/x^2)-k(x+1/x)+(3-k)=0.$$
Let $x+1/x=z$, then we get $h(z)=z^2-kz+1-k=0$ for all real non-zero values of $x$
we have $z< -2~\text{or}~ z> 2.$
Case 1: $f(x)=0$ will have two real roots if $h(z)=0$ has one root less than $-2$ or other greater than 2. This requires
$$(i): h(-2) <0 ~\&~ h(2) <0 \implies k<-5 ~\text{or}~ k> 5/3.~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Case 2: For four real roots of  both roots of $h(z)$ are less than -2.
This requires
$$(i): B^2 \ge 4AC \implies  k\le 2\sqrt{2}-2~ \text{or}~k\ge 2\sqrt{2}-2~ \&$$
$$(ii):z_0=k/2<-2 \implies k<-4~\&$$
$$(iii): h(-2)>0 \implies 5+k>0.$$
The overlap of these intervals is  $$-5 <k <-2\sqrt{2}-2~~~~~~~(2)$$
Case 3: Both roots $> 2$ gives null set.
